# How to set an argument group inside a mutually exclusive argument group with argparse?

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

How do I set the arguments so that I get a mutually exclusive group, consisting of an '--more-info' parameter and a group of 3 other required params like '--arg1', '--arg2', '--arg3'?

In other words, how do I get this?

```
script.py [--more-info] [--arg1=something --arg2=something --arg3=something]
```

**I want that users should either use '--more-info', OR use all of '--argn' parameters.** I read the documentation for argparse, but it confused me even more when I had to achieve this. Any ideas?

Comment: `argparse` does not provide anything like this.  An `argument-group is just from help display, it does nothing special when parsing.  The mutually-exclusive-group is a simple, flat xor test.

Comment: I think, you have to write custom logic.